# Dynamic creation of prims in second life (linden-scripting-language)

Tags: linden-scripting-language

I am an experienced programmer, but new to second life / LSL.  I was wanting to be able to algorithmically create structures, buildings, objects, etc.  But, I cannot find a function that will actually "create" a new prim with a given set of properties and place it in the environment.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily - what you'd need to do is have a base controller prim, which contains a second prim.

This second prim would have a script in which when rezzed would listen to the base controller, and act on parameters passed to it by transforming it's own properties.